# Trying to use one separated schema for SymmetricDS config tables in MySQL

Tags: symmetricds

I have created one separate schema for the SymmetricDS tables in the source node. There are other two schemas in this node, and the problem is that, when symmetricds starts, I get several warnings like this:

"Could not find any database tables matching 'schema1.table1' in the datasource that is configured"

In mysql, I created a user that can read and write in symmetricds config schema, but only can read the tables from the other schemas. I have also created triggers specifying source schema names. And in target node properties file I use the connection URL pointing to symmetric config schema.

Could you help me find out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to this problem.

According to this post https://sourceforge.net/p/symmetricds/discussion/739236/thread/c9e61a44/#b81f I should be using SOURCE_CATALOG_NAME in trigger table instead of SOURCE_SCHEMA_NAME.

By doing this, SymmetricDS has recognized the two schemas in the source.